# Why is the Stack Overflow cookies consent screen persistent

Tags: discussion

I'm getting annoyed by the fact that this new Stack Overflow cookies consent screen stays persistent and hinders my experience, every time I open a new page, it just goes ahead and opens up again, how do I prevent this from happening?

[image: Stackoverflow cookies consent screen]

Comment: You are actively blocking the cookies. Don't...

Comment: Your question *may* not be a duplicate, but until you verify that the issue is *not* the settings in your browser, any browser extensions, your OS, and/or your network infrastructure, then it's assumed that this is a duplicate of the problem being in your settings or setup. You're welcome to [edit] to add significant details which might indicate that it's not an issue in your settings or setup (or that multiple other people are also experiencing the problem).

Comment: I am not blocking the cookies, I use brave browser and all shields are down for SO, I accept the consent every time it pops up, so what now?

Comment: Brave browser is, unfortunately, [not a supported browser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need). Given Brave's focus on privacy, I would not be surprised that there's settings (or basic choices made by the browser designers) which are specifically preventing the cookie popup from functioning as designed. In addition to the sites listed in the above linked Q&A, you will also need to not have restrictions on cookielaw.org.

Comment: Based on a comment below "[How do I permanently set my cookie preferences?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387379/271271)", it looks like at least one other person is having similar problems when using Brave. Also mentioned in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362091/the-cookie-consent-dialog-coming-from-cookielaw-org-keeps-popping-up#comment1298558_363872).

Comment: I've been on SO for over 4 years, been using brave for over 2 years, I've not changed my configuration at least for this whole year, I started experiencing this issue less than two months ago, so something really doesn't seam right and I doubt if it's coming from my own end.

Comment: BTW, it doesn't happen here on meta, and it doesn't happen on other stack exchange site.

Comment: Stack Overflow just can't get cookies right, so we're gonna keep seeing questions like this. Nobody at HQ cares enough, because the ones being annoyed by this are people who use privacy-sensibe browsers or settings and according to the bugs, the reports and the responses those can just get lost.

Comment: Now it’s happening for me (on mobile, anyway) as of sometime after last night AFAICT.